# How to get the same datetime value of circuits downtime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble to get this output data (See snapshots) [image]

The need is to get the same downtime of all circuits under one customer.
I tried to use the following:

- Use Datediff of MaxDownStartDate and MinDownEndDate but this won't work if there's no samedowntime or there is a multiple same downtime for the day.
- Use flagging for hourly range (ex. 00-01, 00-02, etc..) as column but this too much to handle since the data is by seconds level
- Use of script task to handle looping of per row data to check by second level if the DownstartDate of 1 circuit is also within the downstartdate for all circuit

As per the snapshot:

DownStartDate - DownEndDate = MinuteDownTime(hour:minute format)
Yellow and Green Highlighted is the SameDownTime of all Circuits under customer "TestCustomer". 
The total sum of these interval is the SameDownTime

Any suggestions? Whats the best practice on this?
Does using looping/cursor in mssql is an ideal to use?
Is this possible to handle alone by SQL Query only?

Any inputs will do.

Comment: Please clarify what should be the output and what's the logic behind it: what should be start of circuit and what should be the end? What do particular columns mean?

Comment: Base from example. There are Circuits A, B, C, D. The need is to get the same down time (referring to the datedifference of Start and End datetime)

Comment: If all circuits down at 2 to 4 AM same day, then the same down time is 2 hours. 
If not all circuits then no need to do any math.

Comment: So, in your example all down times are different. So, what is with that? Also, what are these colors for?

Comment: I have updated the question. Green and Yellow means the same downtime of all circuits. Sorry mate, I don't know how to format my questions neatly

Comment: From what I see and guess: whole circuit is A-B-C-D (in any order), so every 4 rows we have the whole cicuit. Now, to get the `SameDownTime` we take maximum from start times in particular circuit and minimum from end times in the circuit. Based on that, we aluclate the difference, i.e. `SameDownTime`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. But there may be 2 or more times which might happen in a day. Ex. 1 am to 5 am all downtime and 9 PM to 11 PM ALL circuits down at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
declare @x table(Customer varchar(20), Circuit char(1), DownStartDate datetime, DownEndDate datetime)
insert into @x values
('TestCustomer', 'A', '11/20/2017 00:00:00', '11/20/2017 04:07:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'C', '11/20/2017 01:00:00', '11/20/2017 03:15:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'D', '11/20/2017 01:20:00', '11/20/2017 04:00:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'B', '11/20/2017 02:30:00', '11/20/2017 05:20:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'C', '11/20/2017 20:07:00', '11/20/2017 23:10:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'A', '11/20/2017 21:07:00', '11/21/2017 00:07:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'B', '11/20/2017 21:07:00', '11/20/2017 23:15:00'),
('TestCustomer', 'D', '11/20/2017 22:07:00', '11/20/2017 23:40:00')

select CircuitNo,
       Customer,
       MAX(DownStartDate) as DownStartDate,
       MIN(DownEndDate) as DownEndDate,
       DATEDIFF(minute, MAX(DownStartDate), MIN(DownEndDate)) as [SameDownTime]
from (
    select *, (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select NULL)) - 1)/4 + 1 as [CircuitNo] from @x) as a
group by Customer, CircuitNo
```

Here's **[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96c72/1)** to try :)

Comment: Thanks ! Will try this dynamically.